# Nav Bar not opening external Link

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, navbar

The link to the website is www.kerrycancersupport.com  - In the navigation, all links work bar the 'Donate' button, which links to another website.  I think it's jQuery related but I'm not too sure.  The follow is the HTML for the nav bar.

```
<!-- Main Menu -->
    <div class="main-menu-container navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- responsive navigation -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-    toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <!-- /.navbar-toggle -->
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <h1>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
                                <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png"  alt="Logo" rel="hoome">
                            </a><!-- /.navbar-brand -->
                        </h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-header -->

                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Main navigation -->
                    <ul id="headernavigation" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#volunteer">Timetable</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="http://www.mycharity.ie/charity/kerrycancersupportgroup/" class="donate" target="_blank">Donate <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>

                    </ul>


                    <!-- /.nav .navbar-nav -->
                </nav>

                <!-- /.navbar-collapse  -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#main-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.main-menu-container -->
    <!-- Main Menu End -->
```

---

Comment: Your code actually works, nothing seems to be wrong in your code, make sure you have added the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js in your file.

Comment: If you can't get it working then could you post an example where we can see it not working? Then we can help :)